# Using Lua package (LuaSocket) with HAProxy

Tags: lua, haproxy, luasocket

I have installed HAProxy with Lua 5.3.1, and also LuaSocket.

I have LUA_PATH and LUA_CPATH defined:

```
export LUA_PATH="/usr/local/share/lua/5.3/?.lua;?.lua"
export LUA_CPATH="/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/?.so;?.so"
```

and I'm using LuaSocket in my .lua file

```
core.register_fetches("myfunc", function(txn)

    ...
    local http = require("socket.http")    
    r, e = http.request("http://localhost:5001/api/Registry/")
```

however I can see from `journalctl -xe` that it isn't working

```
Dec 11 23:27:33 ip-172-31-5-92 haproxy[16731]: [ALERT] 344/232733 (16734) : Lua sample-fetch 'myfunc': runtime error: /home/ubuntu/haproxy-mapping.lua:12: module 'socket.http' not found:
Dec 11 23:27:33 ip-172-31-5-92 haproxy[16731]:         no field package.preload['socket.http']
Dec 11 23:27:33 ip-172-31-5-92 haproxy[16731]:         no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.3/socket/http.lua'
Dec 11 23:27:33 ip-172-31-5-92 haproxy[16731]:         no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.3/socket/http/init.lua'
Dec 11 23:27:33 ip-172-31-5-92 haproxy[16731]:         no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/socket/http.lua'
Dec 11 23:27:33 ip-172-31-5-92 haproxy[16731]:         no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/socket/http/init.lua'
Dec 11 23:27:33 ip-172-31-5-92 haproxy[16731]:         no file './socket/http.lua'
Dec 11 23:27:33 ip-172-31-5-92 haproxy[16731]:         no file './socket/http/init.lua'
Dec 11 23:27:33 ip-172-31-5-92 haproxy[16731]:         no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/socket/http.so'
Dec 11 23:27:33 ip-172-31-5-92 haproxy[16731]:         no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/loadall.so'
Dec 11 23:27:33 ip-172-31-5-92 haproxy[16731]:         no file './socket/http.so'
Dec 11 23:27:33 ip-172-31-5-92 haproxy[16731]:         no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/socket.so'
Dec 11 23:27:33 ip-172-31-5-92 haproxy[16731]:         no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/loadall.so'
Dec 11 23:27:33 ip-172-31-5-92 haproxy[16731]:         no file './socket.so' from [C] global 'require', /home/ubuntu/haproxy-mapping.lua:12 C function line 4.
```

I'm surprised that it cannot find `/usr/local/share/lua/5.3/socket/http.lua` because it's there:

```
me$ ls -l /usr/local/share/lua/5.3/socket
total 56
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 10640 Dec 11 21:31 ftp.lua
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  3698 Dec 11 21:31 headers.lua
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 14588 Dec 11 21:31 http.lua
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  8074 Dec 11 21:31 smtp.lua
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  3766 Dec 11 21:31 tp.lua
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 11675 Dec 11 21:31 url.lua
```

It is saying

```
  no file './socket.so' from [C] global 'require', /home/ubuntu/haproxy-mapping.lua:12 C function line 4.
```

is that the core of the issue?  There is no `socket.so` on the machine

Update: forgot to mention that I can use LuaSocket from Lua directly, just not when it's embedded in HAProxy.

Update 2: I suspect permissions.  I ran strace on it and found

```
open("/usr/local/share/lua/5.3/socket/http.lua", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

and I know that haproxy is running as the user `haproxy`

```
me   :/usr/local/share/lua/5.3/socket$ ps -o user= -p 3273
haproxy
```

and yet if I switch user to `haproxy` I can read the file

```
me   :/usr/local/share/lua/5.3/socket$ su - haproxy
Password:
No directory, logging in with HOME=/
$ more /usr/local/share/lua/5.3/socket/http.lua
...listing...
```

and I also changed owner of the http.lua file to `haproxy` and it still can't open the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only assume this is something to do with the context that the Lua function runs with-in when it is called, because changing the code to

```
local http = require("socket.http")    
core.register_fetches("myfunc", function(txn)
    ...
```

worked.

UPDATE: according to this https://www.arpalert.org/src/haproxy-lua-api/1.7/index.html during initialization you can DNS lookups but in runtime mode you cannot.  It doesn't say anything about files but it seems reasonable to believe you can't do files either.